# Haskell - Multiple statements in Let and Where cause error

Tags: haskell

I have this code with let which is causing an error(parse error on input last)

```
mergeSort2 :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Int -> [a]
mergeSort2 [] _ = []
mergeSort2 [a] _ = [a]
mergeSort2 a =
    let first = take ((length a) `div` 2) a
        last = drop ((length a) `div` 2) a
    in if (first > n) && (last > n) 
            then merge2 (mergeSort2 first) (mergeSort2 last)
            else isertionsort a
```

and this code with where causing the same error:

```
mergeSort2 :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Int -> [a]
mergeSort2 [] _ = []
mergeSort2 [a] _ = [a]
mergeSort2 a =
    if (first > n) && (last > n) 
        then merge2 (mergeSort2 first) (mergeSort2 last)
        else isertionsort a
            where first = take ((length a) `div` 2) a
                  last = drop ((length a) `div` 2) a
```

But the following code works, despite using where:

```
mergeSort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
mergeSort [] = []
mergeSort [a] = [a]
mergeSort a =
  merge (mergeSort first) (mergeSort last)
     where first = take ((length a) `div` 2) a
           last = drop ((length a) `div` 2) a
```

Comment: Where's the `Int` argument in the last equation of `mergeSort2` in both examples?

Comment: Hmm, looks ok to me.  Check that you are consistently using spaces to indent--no tabs.

Comment: Side note: it is more efficient to use [SplitAt](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:splitAt) than `take` and `drop` separately. That's what it's made for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your source file has mixed tabs and spaces. Note, for example, that the `let` line is indented with a tab, but the line below it is indented with spaces. To be considered to have the same indentation, lines must be indented with the exact same character, not merely characters which, for some tab-width settings, look the same.